# Cant get expected result

Tags: java

This is coding I needed to implement in my project when I am calling method `getClassId()` in my servlet it returns one and first value from the table however table contains many records.When I use `System.out.println(rs.getString(clId)) ;` in `getClassId()` method it displays correct output. Simply I can Say it does not iterate only once through `rs.getString()` when I call `getClassName()` in  `getClassId()`.

```
public List<String> getClassId() {
    Statement stmt = null;
    List<String> stList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Con = conManager.getConnection();
        stmt = Con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM classes";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
            stList = getClassName(rs.getString(clId));

        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return stList;
}

public String getClassName(String id) {
    String str = "";
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        Con = conManager.getConnection();
        stmt = Con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM classes where clId="+id;
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()) {
            str = rs.getString("className");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: you coded it to call that method as long as there's a next line, so of course it's called more than once.

Comment: Is this the actual code? You are assigning the result of a method that returns a String to a `List<String>` variable, so it shouldn't pass compilation.

Comment: You haven't asked a question!

Comment: It's not really clear what you *expect* this code to do.  Nor does it seem that this code would even compile in the first place.  But even aside from the compilation problem, it *looks like* this code is designed to return a single value, so what's the problem?

Comment: You have described your code, and the question is?

Answer (score 1):

The getClassName() method here returns the className value in the last row found in the database resultset as :

`while(rs.next()){
         str = rs.getString("className");
  }`

Clearly **str** contains the last value in the resultset.

Now getClassId() method invokes getClassName() by iteratively passing the values of **clId** but in the getClassId() method, you are reassigning the value to stList as given below [even this should fail at the time of compilation as String value cannot be assigned to a List datatype..Please check]:

```
while(rs.next() ){
  stList = getClassName(rs.getString(clId));
 }
```

Instead try using the below code :

```
while(rs.next()){
     stList.add(getClassName(rs.getString(clId)));
  }
```

This will add all the values returned by getclassName() to the arrayList.

Hope that helps..